# Angular ui-router case-insensitive query param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string

Consider this state definition:

```
$stateProvider.state("someState", {
   url: "/path?someParam",
   controller: function($stateParams){
       console.log("$stateParams", $stateParams.someParam);
   }
});
```

When navigating to ***/path?someParam=abc***, `$stateParams.someParam` is `"abc"` as expected.

I want it to be the same when navigating to ***/path?someparam=abc***. 
How to achieve it?

P.S.
`$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);` doesn't solve this issue!

Comment: $urlMatcherFactory.caseInsensitive(true); doesnt solve? You are using $urlMatcherFactoryProvider ...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Nope
`$urlMatcherFactory` and `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` are essentially the same.

Comment: But why are you trying to make this? Doesnt a simple if solves your problem?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I want it to be case-insensitive

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out @AlirezaMirian?

Comment: @UnionP no, not a general solution, but in my case, I needed three different cases to be handled. I resolved that by normalizing that param in `onEnter`:

onEnter: function($stateParams, $location) {
                $stateParams.refId = $location.search().refid || $location.search().refId || $location.search().RefId;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what the OP (Alireza Mirian) posted, I am using the model below.  It allows for a variety of spellings, as well as making it case-insensitive.

```js
$stateProvider.state("someState", {
    url: "/path?otherParam",
    controller: "someController",
    onEnter: function ($stateParams, $location) {
        var parameterOptions = ['parameterOne', 'paramOne', 'firstParameter'];
        var queryParameters = $location.search();
        $stateParams.membershipId = undefined;

        // Loops through the query-string parameters to identify a particular parameter, using a variety of spellings, regardless of case
        for (var p in queryParameters) {
            if (queryParameters.hasOwnProperty(p) && parameterOptions.indexOf((p + "").toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                $stateParams.membershipId = queryParameters[p];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```